# How to use block function with "start_background_task" in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm setting up a new server using Flask.
It push images from server to web with flask_socketio and zmq.
I want to use zmq.recv() as block function.
However it will block flask. All message from web will be blocked.
How can I use block function in flask,without socketio.sleep()

I have tried set zmq.NOBLOCK to zmq.recv(). Then add socketio.sleep(0.001). It worked, but it's very ugly.

Here is my code.

```
ctx = zmq.Context()
sock = ctx.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
sock.bind("tcp://*:9988")


def recvThread():   
    while True:     
            img = sock.recv()   
                socketio.emit("frame", img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_zmq()
    with thread_lock:
        if thread is None:
            socketio.start_background_task(target=recvThread)
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Is there any flag can be used to this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have soled this problem by replace zmq with eventlet.green.zmq. 
[Ref](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/951)